# WPF DataGrid horizontal scrollbar not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, scroll

I have created simple DataGrid with 4 columns, which go outside the bounds of DataGrid, and horizontal scrollbar is not showing. I tried setting width to each column but nothing changed. Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Height="200" Width="200" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 3" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 4" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is what I get:

[image]

I have also tried wrapping DataGrid with ScrollViewer. Nothing. How can I make scrollbar appear?

Comment: Have you tried to set `CanContentScroll` to `true`? Also, I think thad when the `Datagrid` is empty, the `ScrollViewer` doesn't handle anything. Can you try to fill the columns and see if the scrolling appears?

Comment: Yes, scroll appears once you have content in DataGrid and this is the default behavior of DataGrid. I am not sure how to override this i.e. how to display scroll even if there is no data

Comment: @Damascus You are right. When I set ItemsSource scrolling works. Thanks. Please post your comment as answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that when the `Datagrid` is empty, the `ScrollViewer` doesn't handle anything. Try to fill the columns by adding an `ItemsSource`, the scrolling should therefore appear :)

Answer (score 22):

I also very much dislike this behavior, since I use header filters. My "hack" is much easier than the above: simply place the data grid inside a new `ScrollViewer` with `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility=Auto` and `VerticalScrollBarVisibility=Disabled` (the DataGrid already handles that one fine). Like so:

```xml
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <DataGrid>
        ...
    </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Sure, it's more controls on the page, but a lot easier than the hacky code above. So far I haven't found a way to make the data grid do this automatically.

The side effect of this solution may be the vertical scrollbar hidden until you scroll to the right.

Comment: caveat - do not use * for datagrid column width if you want horizontal scroll bar to be visible on column resizing

Comment: With this solution it always uses the outer horizontal scroll bar even if there are items in the list. This means the vertical scroll bar of the scrolls out of view, which isn't really feasible.

Comment: If mouse wheel does not work for vertical scrolling see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16235785/3670437).

Comment: Row headers would go out of the visible area.

Comment: @lauren I have tried what you hav ementioned here, then horizontal scroll bar appears perfectly but as you mentioned Vertical scroll bar is not appear until it;s moved to left side . Can u give some advice about this?

Answer (score 4):

this was actually a major issue to me since I am creating many columns and allow the user to filter by having filter controls in the header.

When the user scrolls to the right and places a filter in a column and NO rows are returned because of these criteria then the entire grid would move to the left (all columns to the default left position) and the horizontal scrollbar would disappear so the user can't scroll to the filter column to undo his/her action!!

Major pain!

The 'hack' I have just placed in the code is a way around it:  (the _dv pointing at a DataView from a DataTable)

```
// construct an overall sql filter statement
string sqlFilter = _setttings.SGColumns.GetFilterSQL();

BindingListCollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(gridMain.ItemsSource) as BindingListCollectionView;

if (view != null)
    view.CustomFilter = sqlFilter;      // "XGROUP = 'E' AND GEOG = 'U'";

if (view != null && _dv.Count == 0)
{
    gridMain.ItemsSource = null;
    gridMain.Items.Add("hello");
    _RowHeightTemp = gridMain.RowHeight;
    gridMain.RowHeight = 0;
}
else
{
    if (gridMain.Items.Count == 1 && gridMain.Items[0].ToString() == "hello")
    {
        gridMain.Items.Clear();
        gridMain.ItemsSource = _dv;
        view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(gridMain.ItemsSource) as BindingListCollectionView;
        view.CustomFilter = sqlFilter;
        gridMain.RowHeight = _RowHeightTemp;
    }
}
```

This now ensures that the grid stays in its exact position when the no rows are displayed!

Answer (score 2):

The scrolling will work automatically as soon as you add some data to the grid.  To test you can apply this code

Name your grid to "grid"

Attached the Window Loaded event

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        grid.Items.Add(new object());
    }
```

You will see the scrolling appears.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is an old one, I have thought that it might help someone. Based on lauren's answer:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <DataGrid x:Name="ScrollDataGrid"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ... >
    </DataGrid>
    <ScrollViewer.Style>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ScrollViewer}}" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ScrollDataGrid, Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ScrollViewer.Style>
</ScrollViewer>
```

If the DataGrid have records, the ScrollViewer doesn't show the scroll bars and uses the scroll bars of the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Set `Datagrid`'s properties as `CanUserAddRows="True" IsReadOnly="True"` and wrap it with ScrollViewer. `CanUserAddRows` gives you an empty row. Empty row retains scrollbar. `IsReadOnly` hides the empty row since it's readonly.

Downside is, when you scroll vertically datagrid headers would be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need horizontal scroll bar.

Two things need to do:

**1. Add property `IsReadOnly="True"` to your DataGrid**

**2. Add `MaxWidth="1200" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` to your `ScrollViewer`**

MaxWidth need to be set, you can change `1200` to any other value as you need.

```xml
<ScrollViewer MaxWidth="1200" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True">

    </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me**

```
<ScrollViewer  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  Width="auto">
    <DataGrid></DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal scroll bar is displayed only if the sum of the column widths exceeds the available width. The simplest approach is to ask WPF to adjust the width of the columns to their content with `Width="SizeToCells"`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Marcel answer I made this version

Window resources:

```xaml
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="NormalCollectionView" Source="{Binding Items}" Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter"/>
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="EmptyCollectionView"/>
```

Datagrid style:

```xaml
<DataGrid.Style>
  <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEmpty, Source={StaticResource NormalCollectionView}}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource EmptyCollectionView}}"/>
        <Setter Property="RowHeight" Value="0"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEmpty, Source={StaticResource NormalCollectionView}}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource NormalCollectionView}}"/>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.Style>
```

```csharp
public MyWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  var emptyCollectionView = Resources["EmptyCollectionView"] as CollectionViewSource;
  emptyCollectionView.Source = new ObservableCollection<MyDataType>
  {
    new MyDataType()
  };
  emptyCollectionView.View.Refresh();
}
```

```csharp
private void CollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
  var datacontext = DataContext as MyDataContextType;
  e.Accepted = datacontext.CheckFilterForLine(e.Item as MyDataType);
}
```

- `emptyCollectionView.View.Refresh();` may not be necessary
- There may be a better way to initialize the "empty" collection in the xaml

I did it that way because I have frozen columns that I thought would not work wrapped with a ScrollViewer. I liked Marcel's answer but did not want to deal with the manual grid items management and at some point trying to implement it, it became spaghetti because of all the events.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a couple columns with Width="*". This causes elastic sizing, which means there's never a need for horizontal scrollbars on the DataGrid. Once I set Width="Auto", the horizontal scrollbar showed up.

The default width is *, so it must be explicitly changed.